# set different look and feels in Swing Application Framework jsr 296

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jsr296

My application uses SAF (jsr 296).
I want to use different look and feels on different platforms:

A default (Java) for Linux

And system (native) for Windows.

**ADDED**:
So far I hardcoded L&F for the Windows OS in the startup() method of my Application class (as suggested by Joy and Thompson):

```
if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
}
```

In the application.properties file, the default L&F is specified.

Is there no better way?

Comment: Metal is not the default Java look and feel anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A default (Java) for Linux. ..system (native) for Windows.

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Will set the look & feel for Windows to the native PLAF, while keeping the (default) Metal PLAF for Linux/Unix & using the default for Mac, which we are reliably informed is named:

```
com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel
```

I would probably recommend Nimbus for the Linux/Unix machines.  The Metal PLAF is so ..last millennium.

Comment: Footnote: On Mac OS, `getSystemLookAndFeelClassName ()` returns `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`, which is the default.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

It will set look and feel based on system on which your application is running.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need so much code to do so. You can create a platform specific property file, or use "system" LnF in the application properties.
More details at http://kenai.com/projects/bsaf

Comment: hmm curious ... how to use/install/deploy a platform specific properties file?